# How to install rails 3.2.2 with Ruby 1.9.3, passenger, nginx and rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I followed [this](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-10-with-rvm-passenger-and-nginx/) tutorial to successfully install Rails 3.0.11 with ruby 1.9.3, passenger, nginx and rvm. But when I tried to configure rails 3.2.2 in similar fashion, I got lots of errors. The main issue is that only the contents in the public/ directory are accessible. I tried creating a Home controller with an index page, added 'root :to => "home#index"' to config/routes.rb and deleted public/index.html. What I'm get is 'something went wrong' page.

I tried precompiling assets, but it didn't help.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 for server. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands.

`$ rake assets:precompile`
Compiles the assets

`$ rake db:setup RAILS_ENV="production"`

Answer (score 0):

In anyway try run following commands:

```
$> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
$> rvm get head
```

and then

```
$> rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: True, we need to make sure we are migrating in production environment.

Comment: yes, it has started working. Had to fix some other issues too. I've written everything in blog here http://ershadk.com/blog/2012/04/05/set-up-rails-3-2-2-with-passenger-rvm-and-ngnix/